ffmpeg: detect CURRENT framerate, not ORIGINAL one
Is there a way with ffmpeg to detect the current video framerate and not the original one?
I have a file that plays at 25 FPS with original framerate set at 23.976.
I changed the video framerate with ffmpeg itsscale feature (and atempo for audio).
Mediainfo now shows this:

but I can't find a way to get the 25.000 FPS information with ffmpeg (nor ffprobe), this is what it detects:


ffmpeg will always detect current frame rate.

No, it detects 23.976 FPS
